How to mount local directory to pod installed with helm chart in minikube?
I am using this odoo helm chart from Bitnami installed on minikube on windows.
Now i am trying to mount my local project repo "project/addons" into the Odoo running pod (in /bitnami/odoo/addons, after investigation..) in order to develop my custom modules. I am not sure where are the different variables and entries that i should add/modify from (probably) the values.yaml file.
For now i have mounted my local "project/addons" into minikube's /data/project with following command:
minikube mount "path/to/project/addons:/data/project"

Then mount /data/project/addons into /bitnami/odoo/addons
I am not sure what's next, or even if my previous command would be a right first step.

Why do you want this in a usually-remote clustered environment?  Can you use a non-clustered environment, like a plain Docker container without Kubernetes; or can you use purely local tools without a container environment at all for day-to-day development?

The reason is i want to reproduce the production environment locally. I have tried docker-compose anyways but facing lot of configuration problems, whereas the helm chart installation always working very well at any time in my local minikube environment. That's the reason why i have decided just to develop straight on it. This will help with faster prod releases, because if i have sucessfully developed a feature locally then it's just a matter of few clicks to deploy it. This is also a business requirement (being able to develop and deploy very fast).
